# Ole DB Provider generate syntax error while sql is working in access

Tags: sql-server, database, ole

I have a strange problem (at least strange for me). When i try this sql in an ole db provider it generates a syntax error but when i run it in ms access, it prompt me to enter all parameters and after i done the syntax works nicely. My question is basicly, where should i start to look for errors?

Here is the sql.

```
 UPDATE ProjectDataTable SET Code = @Code, Description = @Description, ProjectGroup = @ProjectGroup, ProjectManager = @ProjectManager, Parent = @Parent, External = @External, Invoiceable = @Invoiceable, CustomerID = @CustomerID, Customer = @Customer, FixedClient = @FixedClient, AllowPosting = @AllowPosting, ExternalContact = @ExternalContact, TimesheetEntry = @TimesheetEntry, AccessControl = @AccessControl, ContactPerson = @ContactPerson, Assignment = @Assignment, Activity = @Activity, ExtOrder = @ExtOrder, Contract = @Contract, SalesContact = @SalesContact, DateFrom = @DateFrom, DateTo = @DateTo, ActualCurrency = @ActualCurrency, DatePctCompleted = @DatePctCompleted, PctCompleted = @PctCompleted, GLObjectValue1ID = @GLObjectValue1ID, GLObjectValue1 = @GLObjectValue1, GLObjectValue2ID = @GLObjectValue2ID, GLObjectValue2 = @GLObjectValue2, XGLID = @XGLID, XGL = @XGL, InvoiceProject = @InvoiceProject, InvoiceRule = @InvoiceRule, Frequency = @Frequency, Day = @Day, IncPerType = @IncPerType, DateNextCutOff = @DateNextCutOff, DateLastCutOff = @DateLastCutOff, PeriodStart = @PeriodStart, NoOfPeriods = @NoOfPeriods, PriceListID = @PriceListID, PriceList = @PriceList, PriceGroup = @PriceGroup, Overview = @Overview, Info = @Info, InternalInfo = @InternalInfo, Created = @Created, Modified = @Modified WHERE GLObjectValue1ID = 'afb850dd-985a-417e-bc7e-e07678e7701e'
```

Comment: Solved it by putting brackets around my column names, must been a column name that was reserved.

Comment: Show the code where you're setting up the SQL command and calling the database.

Comment: Ty for your effort, since its an sql syntax error I didn't post any of the things you asked for. Problem solved by using brackets and that indicate i had a column with a reserved name, I guess.